# blender export / one sided polygons

Tags: blender, 3d-modelling, copperlicht

I'm really new to 3d modeling, blender, etc.

I created a model with blender (a room). Now I exported it (as .obj) so that I can import it to CopperCube (a tool to create 3d scences).

The problem is, that the walls are only visible from outside. Take a look into the pictures:

Blender:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/341/blenderg.png/

CopperCube:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/829/coppercube.png/

I asked the forum of CopperCube and they said that there are only one-side polygons (or flipped). Is there a way to change this? Sorry, but I am a total beginner with this...

Here's the answer of the CopperCube forum:

> I don't know blender, but are there any options you can change for exporting? It looks like your model just has one sided polygons, or the normals are flipped for some of them.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the normals checkbox checked in OBJ export options (at the left side, it's off by default):

[image]

You will need to model your room to have slim cubes instead of planes whenever they should be visible from both sides.

You can display the normals in Blender in edit mode. In *Properties* (N) scroll down to Mesh Display and check the type of normals you want to see and their length.

To recalculate the normals or flip their direction go to the *Tool Shelf* (T) in the *Normals* section.

[image]