# Texture is "inverted"

Tags: textures, blender, blender-2.61

I just started using Blender yesterday so please go easy. I'm using Blender 2.64a on OS X.

I created this scene: a single plane and a playing card (a flattened cube).

The top and bottom faces of cube each have their own material and texture (the card face images). In the example render I simply duplicated a card and then rotated it so that I could see its "back".

The back texture is inverted while the front face is correct. I'm obviously doing something wrong.

I haven't changed any other settings.

Thank you in advance, 
CS

[image]

Comment: Should be migrated to Blender SE http://blender.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check that your "mapping" properties are set up properly. The default viewport in blender always shows UV-mapped textures, even if the material uses a generated mapping.

A hot tip is to turn on GLSL in the viewport, since that will more accurately display your materials than Multitextured.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the normals are wrong. To check this go in edit mode and enable *Normals:* / *Face*. Select all faces or vertices and recalculate them. If there are still normals ponting in the wrong direction you need to flip them manually.

Have a look at the 2nd part of [blender export / one sided polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953308/blender-export-one-sided-polygons/12969365#12969365) to get more details and screenshots.

Comment: Thanks for the help - really appreciate it. I have looked at the face and vertex normals and they appear to be correct. Even if I "Flip Direction" and "Recalculate" the texture is still inverted in the resulting render. Please see http://goo.gl/O5w3v

Comment: Sounds like you have to mirror the texture in UV editor